# Is there a *-automorphism of a c*-algebra not equal to identity?

Tags: functional-analysis

If A is a $C^*$-algebra and $\phi: A\to A$ is a *-isomorphism, can we conclude that $\phi$ is identity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, of course not, unless $A=\mathbb C $ (and maybe some fringe cases). For any nontrivial C $^*$-algebra $A $, nontrivial automorphisms exist.

Concretely, if $A $ is non-abelian,  then  any non-central unitary $u $  induces an automorphism $x\longmapsto uxu^*$. When $A\simeq C (X) $, any nontrivial homeomorphism of $X $ induces a nontrivial  automorphism of $C (X) $.

Comment: Small remark: there are compact metric spaces without non-trivial homeomorphisms (Philips, Weaver "The Calkin algebra has outer automorphisms").

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44820/does-every-locally-compact-second-countable-space-have-a-non-trivial-automorphis

Comment: Nice. $ \ \ \ $